# Не получается использовать flex-start/flex end

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Мне нужно чтобы к левому краю прижался логотип, а список с ссылками к правому краю.
Как это сделать используя *флекс*? 
Что я упустил?

Html/css код:

```css
/* --------------- reset.css --------------- */
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, em, img, strong, sub, sup, b, u, i,  dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;                               /* обнуляем отступы и убираем бордюры */
 vertical-align: baseline;          /* приводим все к одной базовой линии */
 background: transparent;      /* чтобы не проскакивали левые фоны, установленные по умолчанию */
 font-size: 100%;                     /* размер шрифта всем одинаковый */
}
a {                                            /* ссылка не в общем списке чтобы не сбрасывать outline по умолчанию */
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-size:100%;
 vertical-align:baseline;
 background:transparent;
 outline:none;
}
table {      /* устраняем отступы между ячейками таблицы */
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 border-spacing: 0;
}
td, td img {
 vertical-align: top;   /* возвращаем привычное вертикальное выравнивание */
} 
input, select, button, textarea {
 margin: 0;     /* убираем отступы по умолчанию для элементов форм (в частности для checkbox и radio) */
 font-size: 100%;    /* делаем размер шрифтов везде одинаковым */
 outline: none;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
 padding: 0;     /* убираем внутренние отступы для текстовых полей */
}
input[type="checkbox"] {   /* вертикальное выравнивание чекбоксов и радиобатонов относительно меток */
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
input[type="radio"] {
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
sub {
 vertical-align: sub;
 font-size: smaller;
}
sup {
 vertical-align: super;
 font-size: smaller;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display:block;
}
nav ul {
  list-style:none;
}
/* --------------- /reset.css --------------- */

/* --------------- базовые настройки ---------*/
html {
 min-height:100%; /* всегда показываем вертикальную полосу прокрутки  */
}
body {
 color: #606060;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 1em; /* используем безопасные шрифтовые CSS стеки */
 min-height:100%;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a, a:visited { /* порядок правил для ссылок имеет значение */
 color: #58c93a;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color: #fdf208;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:focus, a:active {
 color: #c83867;
 text-decoration:none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 font-weight:normal;
}
img{

 max-width:100%;
}
.clr{
 clear:both;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
/* --------------- /базовые настройки ---------*/

header{
 background: #292929;
 
}

.center-block-main{
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width: 990px;
 display:flex;
}
.logo{
 justify-content:flex-start;
}
.main-menu{
 justify-content:flex-end;
}
.main-menu li{
 font-weight: 600;
}
.main-menu a{
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>Company Name - Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="center-block-main">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" class="logo"></a>
   <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Journal</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лишние стили я убрал так как их надо хранить в отдельном файле и подключать отдельно 
а всё остальное делается так :

flex : применяется для родителя и после `align-items:center`, у вас это `center-block-main` и потом уже для ul и всё

```css
.center-block-main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 990px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

.main-menu li {
  font-weight: 600;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.main-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-block-main">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Company Logo" class="logo"></a>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Journal</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно реализовать то же самое, только используя flex start/end?

Comment: https://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/